# Postman - Push GCM to iOS with Postman

Tags: ios, cordova, push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, postman

I am trying to test GCM to my app with Postman. But It is not authorized.
In the header i put for

Key : The Server key (auto created by Google Service)

Value : application/json

And in Body - Raw :

```
{ "data": {
    "score": "5x1",
    "time": "15:10"
  },
  "to" : "lKVLmzMmvoU:APA91bFrbpmT4IAxS-rN9sr_y8-YDgrySaC7bMx3Pm_Qd-uEb7dfMnMaJRvNfPTj9c1YdhBJp6ClbsIvMKogmet9V0-HV_sgkBNUx59Rq25Ccbys0NWuuh_Mpd7ryK-98pxRV7B2WW63"
}
```

The value for "to" is the token I got from the GCM Registration.

But I have this response :

```
<HTML>
    <HEAD>
        <TITLE>Unauthorized</TITLE>
    </HEAD>
    <BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
        <H1>Unauthorized</H1>
        <H2>Error 401</H2>
    </BODY>
</HTML>
```

[image: postman]

Thank you !

Comment: How are you formatting the key within the header?

Comment: well the fact is I don't really know. I just take the value given in the console of xcode. 
Moreover, I am using phonegap push plugin for it.
For the key in the header i take the key given in console.developper of google

Comment: I have it working within Postman, my header value is: `key=AIza.......`

Comment: Yes I have the same kind

Comment: What endpoint are you using? Mine is: `https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send`

Comment: I tried with this endpoint but I still have the same value

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/121753/discussion-between-ollie-and-guillaume-kotarba).

Answer (score 1):

Each line within Postman is a key-value pair, your values should look something like this:

[image]

Postman have a great guide [here](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/requests) with lots more helpful tips.

Comment: If I test the url : https://gcm-http.googleapis.com/gcm I have invalid tokenFormat